# How To Get Facebook user's "tid" parameter

Tags: facebook

I sniffed a bit when sent a message to a friend and found that there is a simple post message sent that contains a "tid" parameter .By this parameter Facebook knows whom to send the message.

So far I didn't find any relevance of this parameter to user id or other aliases.

Does anyone knows how can I get this "tid" parameter from user who is not my friend ?
(because if he is a friend I can just fetch it from a source code when opening a message dialog page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the tid is what is the `to` field of this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: Yes ! That's the one ! But the Problem is that I need all of those access Tokens and stuff.Actually I don't use an application,so I have no way to get user token , or do I ?

Comment: You will need an app id to get a token to be able to send messages using facebook APIs

Comment: Good.I have an app ID , but as far as I know user must grant permissions to my app and only after that I can fetch his token.And that ain't suits my needs .

Comment: If you have an App Id, then you've agreed to the rules/regulations and restrictions of being a 3rd-party Facebook developer.  You will need to play by their rules to play in their sandbox.

Comment: I've got your point.Can't argue with what you're saying here.Well..I gues there is always another way to do what need to be done :)

Comment: Did you find another way?

Answer (score 0):

This is the actual solution because you can use the public id and it will redirect you to the tid :)

```
https://m.facebook.com/messages/thread/*your fbid here*/
```